# Issue on Hovering another element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an effect on:

> Hover the image > change the link below's color

But I can't make it work properly. I can only make this effect work if I target the whole first container `.clearfix`, but how can I make it work in a way that only if I hover the `img` and not the whole `.clearfix` element, will change the link's color?

```css
.clearfix:hover > b a {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<li class="clearfix">
    <div class="zitem"><a href="#"><img class="recent_thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/270/142/sports"/></a></div>
    <b><a href="#">Random Title text</a></b>
<br>
</li>
```

I've also tried these:

```
.clearfix:hover + b a { ... }
.clearfix:hover ~ b a { ... }
```

But it doesn't seem to work or do anything... maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: That is going to be impossible with pure CSS because the `a` itself is neither a sibling nor a child/descendant of the `img` which is the reference element. At best you can try `.zitem:hover + b a {...}` or `.zitem:hover ~ b a {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
.zitem:hover + b a {
    color:red;
}
```

`div` with `zitem` class and `<b>` element are sibling so sibling selectors (adjacent + or general ~) will work on these.

Comment: Thanks a lot this did the job! :D

Answer (score 0):

This will sought out your problem---

```
.zitem:hover + b a {
    color:#ff0000;
}
```